# For a WordPress plugin, can composer's post-install-cmd script run from the toplevel WordPress install?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, wordpress-plugin-creation

I maintain a WordPress plugin, an ordinary plugin (not mu). When activated, it has one php file that needs to be copied from within the plugin's directory to WordPress's mu-plugins directory. ([Long story](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/wordpress/filtering-database-changes-during-wordpress-updates/).) When the plugin is installed and activated from the dashboard everything works well.

Now, I'd like to be able to support users who use php composer to manage their sites. This requires copying that mu-plugin file at the time of `composer install` or `composer update`. I put scripts in the plugin's `composer.json` file to do this. But they don't run when I reference the plugin from the toplevel WordPress `composer.json` file and say `composer install`.

They DO run correctly when I go to the plugin's own directory and say `composer install` after doing the toplevel install.  Is there a way I can get those plugin scripts to run from the toplevel `composer install` (or `composer update`)?

Here's what I have for scripts.

```json
...
 "scripts": {
    "install-mu-filter": [
      "mkdir -p ../../mu-plugins",
      "cp code/assets/mu/my-plugin-mu-plugin-file.php ../../mu-plugins/",
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@install-mu-filter"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@install-mu-filter"
    ]
  }, 
...
```

Comment: I'd very strongly recommend making this part of the plugin itself and skip composer. You can add it as an activation step and you can add a warning, either globally or on your plugin's page, with a link to allow admins to automatically attempt copying it. See how a redis plugin does it here: https://github.com/rhubarbgroup/redis-cache/blob/develop/includes/class-plugin.php#L688

Comment: @ChrisHaas My plugin already offers the technique Till Krüss used for the drop-in in his Redis Object Cache plugin that you mentioned.  I have a feature request from a user to handle this mu-plugin installation via composer; that user runs locked-down folder protections  You "very strongly" suggest I don't do it that way. Why so strong a recommendation? Am I missing something about security or stability?

Comment: Sorry @O. Jones, my “very strongly” was for the feature that I didn’t realize you had already implemented. You might might want to be aware that the folder is movable by the `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` constant. I know WP VIP uses that, but I don’t know if it is common elsewhere.